# Suddenly Ubuntu only sees 4 of 5 hard disks. Anything to do/try?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 22.04, sata

Recently Ubuntu stopped mounting (or even seeing) one of my hard disks. I assumed the disk had failed so I replaced it only to find it's not actually the disk itself. It seems to be something to do with one of the SATA connectors. But it's not "dead", Ubuntu is seeing the disk but not attaching it.

I wondered if there is anything I can do/try to resolve this?

When I connect a disk successfully I get the following `dmesg` output:

```
[1979542.453246] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[1979546.737295] ata4: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[1979547.449311] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[1979547.450138] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[1979547.450147] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]

[1979547.450148] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]

[1979547.450150] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1979547.450158] ata4.00: ATA-7: WDC WD5000AAKS-65TMA0, 12.01C01, max UDMA/133
[1979547.450372] ata4.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[1979547.451337] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[1979547.451344] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]

[1979547.451345] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]

[1979547.451347] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1979547.451583] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[1979547.451643] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD5000AAKS-6 1C01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[1979547.451843] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[1979547.451943] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[1979547.451987] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[1979547.451990] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[1979547.452045] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1979547.472061]  sdd: sdd1
[1979547.497323] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

But when I connect a disk to the 5th SATA connector I get the same up until `ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133` but then nothing else:

```
[1979625.270190] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[1979625.450202] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[1979625.450983] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[1979625.450992] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]

[1979625.450994] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]

[1979625.450995] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1979625.452066] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[1979625.452073] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]

[1979625.452075] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]

[1979625.452077] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[1979625.452165] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with a MSI Z170A motherboard. It has 6 SATA 3 connectors and I have 1 internal HD and 4 hot-swappable SATA caddies all with hard disks.

Comment: They are not the same ... The disk specs, vendor, and model number are not identified in the second case ... This problem looks limited to the caddy and cable at the 5th SATA connector ... Swap them with either of the other working caddies with their disks and cables ... If 5th SATA works then you know what to do and if it doesn't work then the 5th SATA connector on the board is probably damaged and there is not much to do about it ... Nothing to do about it in Ubuntu either as it looks purely hardware related.

Comment: @Raffa thanks for the reply, I had a play with cables and it seems like it's not the caddies or cables so it must be the motherboard storage controller/s. It looks like the 5th (and also 6th) SATA connectors no longer work properly for some reason. Hopefully I can just buy a PCIe 3.0 SATA card to work around the issue?

Comment: There are multiple different solutions for that … But, the most recommended are only two AFAIK … 1) A PCIE SATA card offers the maximum performance and gives you more connectors/channels … 2) A RAID enclosure to SATA is cheaper with probable performance penalty and gives you more disks/bays per an existing SATA connector … The rest of the alternatives e.g. port multiplier/hub are a waste of both money and performance.

Comment: PCIe can be expensive .., So, I would compare that to a new motherboard of the same model as the existing one and change the motherboard instead if the price is close … This will not only provide 6 working channels but a new motherboard as well to add more years to the life of your computer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update for anyone else in future - it did seem to be a hardware/motherboard  issue where the 5th and 6th SATA ports stopped working correctly.

I saw StarTech list Linux compatibility so I purchased a [StarTech 2P6G-PCIE-SATA-CARD](https://www.startech.com/en-gb/cards-adapters/2p6g-pcie-sata-card) for £33 in the UK and it seems to work fine, no config required.